# Custom colors on Bar graphs bar sets MPAndroid Library

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart

I am working on MPAndroid chart library where I am displaying single bar religion values using bar graph. I want to give a color to each BarEntry as per religion name like "Islam" = green, "Christianity" = Blue etc. I have searched many examples on this forum but not able to solve this.

```
List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 20,"Islam"));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 20,"Christianity"));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 20,"Judaism"));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3f,20,"Sikhism"));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f,20,"Hinduism"));

    BarDataSet bSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Marks");
    bSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);

    ArrayList<String> barFactors = new ArrayList<>();
    barFactors.add("Islam");
    barFactors.add("Christianity");
    barFactors.add("Judaism");
    barFactors.add("Sikhism");
    barFactors.add("Hinduism");


    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    BarData data = new BarData(bSet);
    data.setBarWidth(1f); // set custom bar width
    data.setValueTextSize(12);
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    description.setText("Religion analysis");
    chart.setDescription(description);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
    chart.invalidate(); // refresh
    chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new   IndexAxisValueFormatter(barFactors));
```

I am using this library link:

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

[image]

I want bar colors like bottom colors in this picture. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define colors in your colors.xml file as follow:

```
<color name="Islam">#1abc9c</color>
<color name="Christianity">#2ecc71</color>
<color name="Judaism">#3498db</color>
<color name="Sikhism">#9b59b6</color>
<color name="Hinduism">#16a085</color>
```

Also provide your respective color codes in above code.

After that you need to tell bardataset about these colors as follow:

```
barDataSet.setColors(new int[]
            {
                    R.color.Islam, R.color.Christianity, R.color.Judaism, 
                    R.color.Sikhism, R.color.Hinduism
            }, getContext());
```

This will do the job just give the order of colors in an order in which you are giving values to bar dataset.